# jQuery: Stop dropdown menu from collapsing when clicking on its children

Tags: jquery

I have a top nav bar and some of its items trigger dropdowns/slide-downs.

My problem is that whenever I click an item, or actually any area within the dropdown, the dropdown collapses.

What I need help with is figuring out how to avoid collapsing the dropdown when a child element is clicked (or well, anywhere within the dropdown area since I'd like to account for accidental clicks inside the dropdown but that are not actually clicks on a child element).

Here's the basic **HTML** structure I have:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
 <li><a href="#" class="noclick nojs">Select your Topic</a>
  <ul class="nojs" >
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('.dropdown li').click(function() {
  //Hide all other drop downs that are visible, and remove the class 'selected'
  $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected').find('ul:visible').slideUp('fast');

  //Show/Hide dropdowns
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('ul:first', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/zEQVK/1/)**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

stop [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on those children elements so the event doesn't bubble up to the li

```
$('ul.nojs *').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DEfK9/

Comment: Ok `stopPropagation();`, now I finally understand what it means :), you can tell I'm that new to jQuery. I don't have to modify my current script, which is great. It worked perfectly wirey, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zEQVK/3/)** — Attach the `.click()` event to the `<a>` tags instead of the `<li>` tags.

```
$('.dropdown .noclick').click(function(e) {
    // Do stuff.
});
```

Comment: Coby, great idea. Although I didn't pick your answer as the final answer, you have shown me with your example how to approach this next time. Thanks for your help. Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change slideToggle() to slideDown() using snippet below:

http://jsfiddle.net/yrzRu/

```
if ($(this).not('.selected')) {
        $('ul:first', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
```

Comment: with your example now it's not possible to collapse the dropdowns. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zEQVK/10/)

```
$('.dropdown').children('li').click(function() {

    //Show clicked dropdown and add 'selected' class
    $(this).addClass('selected').find('ul').slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide all other dropdowns and remove 'selected' class
    $('.dropdown').children('li').not(this).removeClass('selected').find('ul').slideUp('fast');

});
```

Comment: Same problem as with roasted's, now it's not possible to collapse the dropdowns by clicking on the items themselves. Thanks tho.

Comment: Ohhhh, I didn't realize you wanted that!

Comment: @Ricardo Here you go! Instead of slideDown , we use slideToggle :)  http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zEQVK/7/

Comment: @Ricardo You should at least upvote answers that worked since you didn't specify in your question that you wanted to be able to close the menu.

Comment: I did and I always do upvote answers that deserve it. Also, I didn't specify on my question that the dropdowns should collapse back when clicking on the item itself because I didn't need help with that since I had it already working. On the other hand, your example still doesn't work correctly, the dropdowns do not collapse back when clicking on the items themselves. I'm leaving a link to the fiddle with this issue for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zEQVK/7/. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo Ahhh.. its all good, I guess there was just a little confusion. The fiddle is the wrong revision.  The right one has the slideToggle like in my above answer revision. http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zEQVK/10/

Comment: No problem. Your last fiddle however (rv10), has the same issue I had initially: dropdowns collapse when clicking on the items inside of them. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zEQVK/10/ - Thanks though.