# Keep element open, close when clicked anywhere else

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

When the link (.account) is pressed the dropdown appears. However I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the dropdown to stay down when active and close only when pressed anywhere outside the dropdown

```
        $(".account").click(function(e){

            e.stopPropagation();

            var oBody = $("body")
                oButton = $(".account")

            if (oBody.hasClass("open-says-me") & oButton.hasClass("active")) 
            {
                oBody.removeClass("open-says-me");
                oButton.removeClass("active");

                jQuery(document).off("touchstart click");

            } else {

                oBody.addClass("open-says-me");
                oButton.addClass("active");


                jQuery('html').on("touchstart click", function() {
                        oBody.removeClass("open-says-me");
                        oButton.removeClass("active");
                    });
            }

        });
```

How do I get it to stay open and close only when user clicks/touches anywhere outside the dropdown.
With my actual code, when I click on Button with .account -> Panel Opens -> Click anywhere on document it closes.
However it even closes if you click/touch the panel itself, which isn't what I want, i'm trying to get it so when you click anywhere BUT the dropdown it closes. Thanks for help.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code ? What actually happens ?

Comment: Click on Button with .account -> Panel Opens -> Click anywhere on document it closes. 

However it even closes if you click/touch the panel itself. which isnt what i want, im trying to get it so when you click anywhere BUT the dropdown it closes

Comment: Ok. Please edit question with your additional informations, it will be more clear.

Comment: "However I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the dropdown to stay down when active and close only when pressed anywhere outside the dropdown"

Comment: It does say what you wish, but not what your code actually does wrong. I edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this post : [jQuery: Stop dropdown menu from collapsing when clicking on its children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13350809/4786273) 
if you have a DOM like this :

```
<ul class="dropdown">
 <li><a href="#" class="noclick nojs">Select your Topic</a>
  <ul class="nojs" >
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

you must add this code :

```
$('ul.nojs *').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});​
```

looks like the `.account` you use is like the `.dropdown` of the other post. Have a try with this, and post your DOM in your question if you can't make it work.